# How to get Android/iPhone device unique ID using titanium appcelerator?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

We are using the titanium appcelerator for developing the iPhone and android app. We would like to get the unique device id for user registration. Does titanium has any api to do the same. If not, how will I get the info? Answers with code samples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

Titanium.Platform.getId();

Comment: Titanium.Platform.getId() gets empty value in emulator.. i belive this will give correct value min device. But the method Titanium.Platform.Id also gets blank in emulator. Can you confirm this? Also does this works for both iPhone and Android devices?

Comment: This definitely works for iPhone - even in my simulator. I get a string like: `0000000-0000-1000-8000-001CBDE3E98F`

Comment: Titanium.Platform.id

Take a look at the APi http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Platform-module. I have not tried it on the device.

Comment: This is deprecated as of Titanium Mobile 1.8

Comment: This is restricted by apple so how we can get unique id for IOS?

Answer (score -3):

I donot know about Titanium appcelerator.
But Try with the following code to get device id

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

And you should add the following permission into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Is this code for Android? I think i should be able to write a wrapper method by packing this as a jar and call this from the titanium. But would be better if titanium is providing an API.